# Long equation with left and right justified

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

Good day to all,

I have below equation, the first equation exceeds my margin if written in one line. So I want it appear in two lines which the first line is justified at the left side and the second line is justified at the right. Is this is a good practice or I have to put it in other way, which is accepted by mathematician especially.

[image: This is the output of my latex command]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}\nonumber
\mathbf{c}_m^t(b_0\mathbf{I}_m +b_{1}\mathbf{Q}_{m}+b_{2}\mathbf{Q}^2_{m}+\cdots +b_n \mathbf{Q}_m^n)\mathbf{H}_m=&\\ \label{panjang}
=\mathbf{eQ}_m^{\alpha}(a_0 \mathbf{I}_m^{}+a_1\mathbf{Q}_m+a_2\mathbf{Q}_m^{2}+\cdots+a_n\mathbf{Q}_m^{n})\mathbf{H}_m
\end{eqnarray}
where \(\mathbf{e}=\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{m} & 0 & \cdots & 0\end{bmatrix}\). Rewrite Eqn. \ref{panjang} with
\begin{eqnarray}g_1(\mathbf{Q}_{m})=a_0 \mathbf{I}_m+a_1\mathbf{Q}_m^{}+a_2\mathbf{Q}_m^{2}+\cdots+a_n\mathbf{Q}_m^{ n}\end{eqnarray} 
and 
\begin{eqnarray}
g_2(\mathbf{Q}_{m})=b_0\mathbf{I}_m +b_{1}\mathbf{Q}_{m}+b_{2}\mathbf{Q}^2_{m}+\cdots +b_n \mathbf{Q}_m^n\end{eqnarray} it becomes
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbf{c}_m^t g_{2}(\mathbf{Q}_{m})&=&
\mathbf{e}\mathbf{Q}_m^\alpha g_1(\mathbf{Q}_{m}).
\end{eqnarray}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you. actually there are lines above the equation displayed. I just copied the equation. thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned for example in the [TeX FAQ](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-eqnarray) the use of `eqnarray` is discouraged.

To achieve the layout you want, you can use for example the `multline` environment from `amsmath`. What else can be done is described for example in the [Short Math Guide for LaTeX](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf). I would not put a `=` on the end of the first line. But otherwise I think your approach is the best way to go in this case.

Comment: It is the `multline` not `multiline` environment.  Understandable, even so much that a specific error related to the accidental use of `multiline` instead of `multline` is mentioned in the troubleshooting of the `amsmath` manual :)

Comment: @J M: Oh. Strangely I read `multiline` in the *Short Math Guide* although it really does say `multline`. Guess that's how our mind plays tricks on us. Thanks a lot for the correction.

Comment: great!it works. i couldn't think of looking at other options of equation environment. what i was thinking is how to have other command or renew command.. thanks a lot.

Comment: @azlanaznam: Glad to be of help. Please accept the answer if your problem is sufficiently solved.

Comment: The align environment can also be quite helpful ins ome situations.

Answer (score 4):

I would certainly replace the first `eqnarray` environment with a `multline` environment, as @canaaerus suggests in his answer.

Furthermore, I would also replace the second and third `eqnarray` environments with a *single* `align` environment (with the word `and` inserted with a `\shortintertext` macro), and I'd replace the final `eqnarray` environment with a simple `equation` environment. Basically, there's no good reason for using `eqnarray`, especially as the available alternatives are so much better.

In addition, I'd create a macro to abbreviate the very frequently occurring `\mathbf{Q}` with something shorter, say, `\Q`, i.e., I set up the macro `\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbf{Q}}`. Finally, if you want to have parentheses placed around cross-referenced equation numbers, you can get LaTeX to do this for you automatically if you use the `\eqref` (instead of `\ref`).

Taken together, the following modified MWE results:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter} % just for the MWE
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbf{Q}}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{5} % just for the MWE
\setcounter{equation}{19} % just for the MWE
\begin{multline}\label{panjang}
\mathbf{c}_m^t(b_0\mathbf{I}_m +b_{1}\Q_{m}+b_{2}\Q^2_{m}+\dots +b_n \Q_m^n)\mathbf{H}_m\\ 
=\mathbf{eQ}_m^{\alpha}(a_0 \mathbf{I}_m^{}+a_1\Q_m+a_2\Q_m^{2}+\dots+a_n\Q_m^{n})\mathbf{H}_m
\end{multline}
where \(\mathbf{e}=
\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{m} & 0 & \dots & 0\end{bmatrix}\). Rewrite Eqn.~\eqref{panjang} with
\begin{align}g_1(\Q_{m})&=a_0 \mathbf{I}_m+a_1\Q_m^{}+a_2\Q_m^{2}+\dots+a_n\Q_m^{ n}
\shortintertext{and}
g_2(\Q_{m})&=b_0\mathbf{I}_m +b_{1}\Q_{m}+b_{2}\Q^2_{m}+\dots +b_n \Q_m^n
\end{align} 
so that it becomes
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{c}_m^t g_{2}(\Q_{m}) =
\mathbf{e}\Q_m^\alpha g_1(\Q_{m}).
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]